# How to get a description for each Spacy NER entity?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am using [Spacy NER model](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) to extract from a text, some named entities relevant to my problem, such us DATE, TIME, GPE among others.

For example, I need to recognize the Time Zone in the following sentence:

```
"Australian Central Time"
```

With Spacy model `en_core_web_lg`, I got the following result:

```
doc = nlp("Australian Central Time")
print([(ent.label_, ent.text) for ent in doc.ents])
    
>> [('NORP', 'Australian')]
```

**My problem is**: I don't have a clear idea about what exactly means entity `NORP` and more general what exactly means each Spacy NER entity (leaving aside the intuitive values of course).

I found the following snippet to get the complete entities list, but after that I'm blocked:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.get_pipe("ner").labels
```

I'm pretty new to using Spacy NLP and didn't find what I'm looking for on the official documentation, so any help will be appreciated!

BTW, I'm using Spacy version `3.2.1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most labels have definitions you can access using `spacy.explain(label)`.

For `NORP`: "Nationalities or religious or political groups"

For more details you would need to look into the annotation guidelines for the resources listed in the model documentation under https://spacy.io/models/.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there a list of explanations online? I'd like to avoid installing spacy just to get the explanations.

Comment: @viktorasv See my answer below. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

The whole list is as below. As of February 2023, there are 18 labels in the English model.

```
PERSON:      People, including fictional.
NORP:        Nationalities or religious or political groups.
FAC:         Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.
ORG:         Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.
GPE:         Countries, cities, states.
LOC:         Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water.
PRODUCT:     Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (Not services.)
EVENT:       Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.
WORK_OF_ART: Titles of books, songs, etc.
LAW:         Named documents made into laws.
LANGUAGE:    Any named language.
DATE:        Absolute or relative dates or periods.
TIME:        Times smaller than a day.
PERCENT:     Percentage, including ”%“.
MONEY:       Monetary values, including unit.
QUANTITY:    Measurements, as of weight or distance.
ORDINAL:     “first”, “second”, etc.
CARDINAL:    Numerals that do not fall under another type.
```

Source: [Mikael Davidsson on Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/explorations-in-named-entity-recognition-and-was-eleanor-roosevelt-right-671271117218).